# Maven project builds successfully in Eclipse, but shows compile errors in cmd prompt

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have imported an existing Maven project into Eclipse IDE. I modified some of the code and built the project in Eclipse. There are no build errors.

However, when I ran `mvn clean install` from the command prompt, it is showing a lot of compilation errors. Why is Eclipse not showing errors and whereas Maven shows compilation errors?

Comment: It is related to our Application specific like , symbol not found for a class . I have checked the class is present in Eclipse using Ctrl + Shift + T

Comment: Could you expand your question by the following information: eclipse version, is m2e or m2eclipse installed (or nothing at all), how do you do your build inside eclipse, do you have configured in m2e the Maven you want to use? All of these are relevant to the possible reasons ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't have the concept of the [maven scopes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope). Whereas maven will have  different classpaths depending on the scope--eclipse will only have a single classpath set.

IMHO, I don't trust m2eclipse for builds--just let it assist with development.

Comment: So you mean to say that always run mvn clean install from the command prompt only and not from Eclipse IDE ??

Comment: That's up to you. I'd recommend a continuous build server like jenkins that will run your unit & integration tests. If you're modifying the dependencies, use mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -pl changedmodule -am && mvn -o clean verify -pl changedmodule

Answer (score 1):

Building on TJR's answer, I want to give a concrete example that just happened to me.

I also had a build that "works" in Eclipse, but failed with many Java compiler errors on the command line.  (Thankfully, I always test with 'mvn clean install' before doing a release.)

In my case, I had build some custom hamcrest matchers, but the hamcrest dependencies in my POM were set as: `<scope>test</scope>`  Removing this scope restriction fixed my bug.

Seems like m2e still needs more work.